# Error when calling method on web api controller - .Net Core 1.1 / EF 1.1

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

A few hours ago I posted a question, but in my haste to post the question before going to a meeting, I posted the wrong thing. I have deleted it, and here is the correct version:

I am developing a .Net Core 1.1 Web API using EF Core 1.1, which connects to a MySQL database using Pomelo.
It connects properly, but when I try to read a certain record:

http://localhost:50082/api/houses/3

I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be
>   non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name:
>   index System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRange_IndexException()

Here is what my controller looks like:

```
private readonly InspectionsContext _context;

// GET: api/Houses/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetHouse([FromRoute] int? id)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var house = await _context.Houses.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.HouseId == id);

            if (house == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(house);
        }
```

The error happens on this line:

```
var house= await _context.Houses.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.HouseId == id);
```

House is just a standard class matching the corresponding table in the database. And there IS a house - and only one house - in the database with ID = 3.

Any ideas why I'm getting this error?

**UPDATE:**

Here is the full StackTrace of the error:

> at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRange_IndexException()    at
>   System.SZArrayHelper.get_Item[T](Int32 index)    at
>   lambda_method(Closure , ValueBuffer )    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalMixedEntityEntry..ctor(IStateManager
>   stateManager, IEntityType entityType, Object entity, ValueBuffer
>   valueBuffer)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntryFactory.NewInternalEntityEntry(IStateManager
>   stateManager, IEntityType entityType, Object entity, ValueBuffer
>   valueBuffer)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntryFactory.Create(IStateManager
>   stateManager, IEntityType entityType, Object entity, ValueBuffer
>   valueBuffer)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.StartTrackingFromQuery(IEntityType
>   baseEntityType, Object entity, ValueBuffer valueBuffer, ISet`1
>   handledForeignKeys)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityTrackingInfo.StartTracking(IStateManager
>   stateManager, Object entity, ValueBuffer valueBuffer)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryBuffer.StartTracking(Object
>   entity, EntityTrackingInfo entityTrackingInfo)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass16_0`2.<_TrackEntities>b__0(TOut
>   result)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.SelectAsyncEnumerable`2.SelectAsyncEnumerator.<MoveNext>d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at
>   InspectionsWebApi.Controllers.HousesController.d__4.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\Users\fabsr\Source\Repos\InspectionsWebApi\InspectionsWebApi\Controllers\HousesController.cs:line
>   46

Comment: It fails with every house, or just with that one?

Comment: Id can be null : int? id.  So query can fail if you got a null id.

Comment: Does http://localhost:50082/api/houses?id=3 work?

Comment: Can you post the full exception call stack?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply... Yes it fails with any house, with the same error message. I checked the Id parameter in the Controller, and it is populated with value "3". I tried http://localhost:50082/api/houses?id=3 but that didn't work. I will post full exception stack by editing original question.

Thanks again...

Comment: You tried firstordefault instead of singleordefault ?

Comment: The exception is from EF Core infrastructure, so can't say exactly, but there must be some difference between the model and database. I guess you can't even do `_context.Houses.ToList()`?

Comment: Ok looks like it was some column that, most probably Pomelo, didn't like. I deleted all columns and added only 3 basic columns (Int, bool and varchar) and it works. I'll have to try figure out which column it was... As soon as I figure it out, I'll post... Thanks everyone for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to instantiate your context object. Try making your SingleOrDefault call like:

```
using (var _context = new InspectionsContext()) 
{     
    var house = await _context.Houses.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.HouseId == id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like it was some column that - most probably Pomelo - didn't like. I deleted all columns and kept only 3 basic columns (and int, a bool and a varchar) and it works. I'll have to try figure out which column it was... As soon as I figure it out, I'll post... Thanks everyone for your help